# How to make a math button?

Tags: button, text, fonts, android

I'm doing a calculator project on Android by Eclispe, so I need to write math symbol, like square root or subscript on each button. How do I do it, and do I have to use custom font? I'm still new at this, so any detail info would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user4033 JohnnyP's right, development questions belong on StackOverflow.  That said, you probably don't need a custom font, most common fonts have common math symbols like √.  It might not look great in the font, however.  Check out http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm

Comment: this is off topic, but you can use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java and Android use Unicode, you'll probably find that you can use the symbol you need just by looking up its Unicode number.

For example, the square root symbol is [Unicode character 221A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm) (in hex, 8730 decimal).

You reference this in code like this:

```
button.setText("\u221A");
```

Or in the strings resources like this:

```
<string name="square_root">"\u221A"</string>
```